# Alogorithms exercise

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I would like to know the complexity of this algorithm, I am a bit confused in the notation.

```java
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) 
    for(int j=M-1; j>=i; --j) 
        ++x
```

The answers are:

- `O(min(N,M))`
- `O(N*M)`
- `O(N+M)`
- `O(max(N,M))`

Comment: Time complexity is: `O(N) * O(M)`. In other words: `~O(n^2)`

Comment: What do you think it is, and why do you think that? Give us your thoughts, and show that you at least tried.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: O(N*M)

Explanation:
First, the outer loop is executing N times no matter what.
The inner loop will be executed M times in the first iteration, M-1 times in the second iteration, and so on. This is an Arithmetic progression with a sum of d*(a1+an)/2
Which is 1(M+1)/2 which is O(M).
Multiply O(N) and O(M) will give you O(N*M).